# Is maximum matching in a Bipartite Graph always a perfect matching?

Tags: algorithm, graph, networkx, graph-algorithm

Can Hopcroft-Karp algorithm help in determining the perfect matchings for the bipartite graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A perfect matching is only possible if there's an equal number of vertices in both sets.

It's not possible to find a perfect matching for this graph:

[image]

Even if both sets have the same number of vertices, the maximum matching won't be perfect if edges are missing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your supposition is wrong. A maximum matching in a bipartite graph may not be a perfect matching. Consider the following example:

```
  a1
 / \
b1  b2
```

It is clearly a bipartite graph with sets `A = {a1}` and `B = {b1, b2}`. A maximum matching will consist of a single edge for this graph. We cannot cover all three vertices with just one edge. So, there is no perfect matching.